# Service update paused: update paused due to failure or early termination of task

Tags: docker, devops, docker-swarm

I create service my_service with 12 replication and it work normally, but when i try to update my_image to v2 by running this command:

`$ docker service update --image myimage:v2 --update-parallelism 2  --update-delay 10s image_name`

I am getting this error:

`service update paused: update paused due to failure or early termination of task`

Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Please, post the docker file which generates the `myimage:v2`.

Comment: its not a docker file, it's simple docker command: docker service create --name my_service --network ps-net -p 80:80 --replicas 12 my_image, it was pulled via docker hub

Comment: Please, post the right image id to allow us to reproduce the issue, else we cannot help you!

Comment: this is the images from docker hub: nigelpoulton/tu-demo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found the probleme, there was no space left on my worker node.

Comment: Know how to free space on nodes ?

Comment: Go to the target node and free space or extend space if needed it.